# AADB2C90077: User does not have an existing session and request prompt parameter has a value of 'None'

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have an Angular app that uses [MSAL.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js) and when I try to get an access token I'm receiving the following error:

> AADB2C90077: User does not have an existing session and request prompt parameter has a value of 'None'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was passing the wrong scope value; I had a typo in my tenant name:

```
this.userAgentApplication.acquireTokenSilent(
  'https://{tenantname_with_typo}.onmicrosoft.com/webapi/read')
```